# Nlp library that reconstruct sentense

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, nlp, stanford-nlp

I Looking for an nlp library that can reconstruct word or sentences.

I do not know if space or nltk ca do it.

For example :

th i is a tes t =>  this is a test

mornung => morning

Let'5 pl3 y =>  Let's play

Thanks in advance  for your help

Comment: Please do take some time to read [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and notice that questions asking us to *recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource* are off-topic for SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use packages like,

1)Gingerit : https://github.com/Azd325/gingerit

2)Spacy_grammar : https://github.com/tokestermw/spacy_grammar

3)Language tool : https://github.com/languagetool-org/languagetool

Comment: Kindly refrain from answering off-topic questions, as advised in the community guidelines - please see [Should one advise on off-topic questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276572/should-one-advise-on-off-topic-questions), [“Why shouldn't I answer off-topic questions?” FAQ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262573/why-shouldnt-i-answer-off-topic-questions-faq), and [Should I answer off-topic questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/133552/should-i-answer-off-topic-questions)